# Is there a proper name for "optical image transitivity"?

Tags: optics, terminology, geometric-optics

I've scoured Wikipedia for any evidence that the following statement:

> [paraphrasing] ... all images formed by one device can serve as the object for a second device ...

Has its own proper name. Has anyone seen a proper name for this principle?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_reciprocity

Comment: @JonCuster That's a useful concept, but it's different to what OP is asking about.